# Why doesn't the content of the select box appear?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, session-storage

I have a select box with five options, I want to store the selected option in the `sessionStorage` and it works perfectly, but when I chose an option the select box became empty any help why this happened?

```html
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="alger">alger</option>
    <option value="oran">oran</option>
    <option value="telemcen">telemcen</option>
    <option value="constantine">constantine</option>
    <option value="bejaia">bejaia</option>
</select>
```

```javascript
let state = document.querySelector("#state");

if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("state")) {
    state.value = window.sessionStorage.getItem("state");
}
state.addEventListener("change", function () {
    state.value = window.sessionStorage.setItem("state", this.value);
});
```

Comment: You should not be setting the value. `state.value = ` get rid of it

Comment: `state.addEventListener("change", function () {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("state", this.value);
});`

Answer (score 1):

`window.sessionStorage.setItem` does not return anything. You are setting the elements value to `undefined` so it removes the selection. Get rid of the assignment.

```js
state.addEventListener("change", function () {   
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("state", this.value);
});
```